# How do you create an array with custom indexes?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

For some reason I can't create an array with custom indexes in `Javascript` or `PHP`. I have searched on Google, but I can't find anything when searching on *creating array with custom indexes*. I could swear the code below was working before. So was the code below working before or am I doing something wrong? And if the code below was working before then what is the new way of creating an array with custom indexes?

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $foo = ['bar' => 'baz'];    
?>
```

> Error: Array to string conversion

**Javascript**

```
var foo = ['bar' => 'baz'];
```

> Error:
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: It's not possible in javascript, you can use objects however. `var foo = { 'bar': 'baz' };` As for you array in PHP it's perfectly fine if you use PHP >= 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP started to support shortened syntax for arrays (i.e. `[]` vs `array()`) starting from version *5.4*.

In JavaScript the syntax is different. Maps (or dictionaries) in JS are implemented as objects:

`var foo = { bar: 'baz' };`

And as in some scripting languages (like Python) objects *don't have* internal order for elements. Beware, associated arrays in PHP *do have* an order.

Answer (score 0):

For php use this :

```
$foo = array('bar' => 'baz');
```

For javascript :

```
var foo = {
    'bar': 'baz'
};
```